# Intellij IDEA 11 and Virgo 3.5

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, osgi, integration, eclipse-virgo

Our project had switched from Virgo 2 to Virgo 3.5, and, to my deep frustration, this version doesn't seem to be supported by IDEA's "dmServer" plugin, version 0.9.5.

So I'm looking for some engineers out there who had faced with the same issue, to hear any pointers and possible workarounds. The main value that we anticipate from IDEA\Virgo integration is obviously an ability to debug the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open issue for this problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87505) in YouTrack, upvote to track the progress.